# Self destroy pattern

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

I need an object to do some work each system tick until it's finished, and then I want that object to be released. Is this an ok design pattern?

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) A a;

// This call is done once in a while, and when a is no longer needed it will self destruct.
self.a = [self.a doSomething];
```

where

```
-(A*)doSomething
{
  bool rdy = [self doTheWorkAndReturnTrueIfRdy];
  return rdy ? nil : self; 
}
```

Comment: Why can't your object just release `a` when it's done with it? Objects should not, generally speaking, manage themselves in this way. Also, you can't return a value from a method whose return type is `void`.

Comment: Sorry for the void typo. I've updated the question.

And I quess that I agree about the self management. Maybe I shall use some delegate pattern as Wain suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
-(void)doSomething
{
  bool rdy = [self doTheWorkAndReturnTrueIfRdy];
  return rdy ? nil : self; 
}
```

is defined to not have a return - but you're trying to return something. It also appears like you want it to be called multiple times / block the caller, which either won't work or isn't a good idea.

Consider retaining the worker like you planned, but adding a delegate relationship with the source object. When the worker is finished, call the delegate method. When the source object receives the delegate callback it can release the worker.

Comment: Sorry, the void was a typo. I've updated the question.

But I guess that your suggestion is cleaner.